# Getting list of months in between two dates according to specific format

Tags: python

```py
start = "Nov20"
end = "Jan21"

# Expected output:

["Nov20", "Dec20", "Jan21"]
```

What I've tried so far is the following but am looking for more elegant way.

```py
from calendar import month_abbr
from time import strptime


def get_range(a, b):
    start = strptime(a[:3], '%b').tm_mon
    end = strptime(b[:3], '%b').tm_mon
    dates = []
    for m in month_abbr[start:]:
        dates.append(m+a[-2:])
    for mm in month_abbr[1:end + 1]:
        dates.append(mm+b[-2:])
    print(dates)


get_range('Nov20', 'Jan21')
```

> Note: i don't want to use pandas as that's not logical to import such library for generating dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timedelta` to step one month (31 days) forward, but make sure you stay on the 1st of the month, otherwise the days might add up and eventually skip a month.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def get_range(a, b):
    start = datetime.strptime(a, '%b%y')
    end = datetime.strptime(b, '%b%y')
    dates = []
    while start <= end:
        dates.append(start.strftime('%b%y'))
        start = (start + timedelta(days=31)).replace(day=1)  # go to 1st of next month
    return dates

dates = get_range("Jan20", "Jan21")
print(dates)
```

Comment: Note Feb has 28 or 29 days so if start from Jan then skips over Feb to March.

Comment: @JasonM1 ? I can't reproduce. 1.1. + 31 days is maybe 1.2. So it's February and it will be included. Starting on 1.2. + 31 days is maybe 3.3., so it's March and will be included as well.

Comment: am getting `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'` . i think you meant `from time import strptime` ?

Comment: @Thomas Weller Never mind - Feb-01 + 31 days = Mar-03. Don't like adding 31 days to get to next month but replace(day=1) adjusts for it.

Comment: @JasonM1: unfortunately timedelta has no concept of a month

Answer (score 3):

The date range may span different years so one way is to loop from the start date to end date and increment the month by 1 until end date is reached.

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_range(a, b):
    start = datetime.strptime(a, '%b%y')
    end = datetime.strptime(b, '%b%y')
    dates = []
    while start <= end:
        dates.append(start.strftime('%b%y'))
        if start.month == 12:
            start = start.replace(month=1, year=start.year+1)
        else:
            start = start.replace(month=start.month+1)
    return dates

dates = get_range("Nov20", "Jan21")
print(dates)
```

Output:

```
['Nov20', 'Dec20', 'Jan21']
```